# Too many views in Xcode; alternative?

Tags: xcode, view

I'm an Xcode noob. I have created a view-based project, whose model is [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/onzuo29aaq7l6bv/Senza%20titolo.pdf?token_hash=AAFYqPZW8xCxQjpvNPTOLO8kIdm8HLsgIBfztmXy4u1-_w&dl=1). As you can see from it, I'd have to create lots and lots of view, which is very inconvenient. Is there another way to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to make a dynamic view. You just create a few view controllers and through a storyboard segue you pass the value and you change the UITableView data accordingly.

Here is a good tutorial about storyboard segues: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Basically, when you select a row in you tableview you can pass a value to the pushed view controller so you can change the new content:

Comment: Could you give me further info about how to do this or link me to a tutorial? Thank you!

Comment: Added a link in my answer.